# NoSuchElementException exception handling in reactivex

Tags: java, rx-java, micronaut, reactivex

Using the `io.reactivex.Single` in Micronaut to get the data from the MongoDb reactive, However, if there is no element on  the database the below code throws an exception as `NoSuchElementException`

```
Single.fromPublisher(repository.getCollection(ConstantValues.PRODUCT_CATEGORY_COLLECTION_NAME, Category.class).find(query)).blockingGet();
```

How can I handle the exception, I don't want to use try and catch, is there any other way to handle the exception in rxjava ?

Comment: How do you want to handle it: fallback, default value, etc? You may also consider using `Maybe`.

Comment: If there is no item, then it should return null value

Comment: Try `Flowable.fromPublisher(...).blockingFirst(null)`.

Comment: @akarnokd Thanks, it works.

Comment: Use blocking operators is a bad practice. Try to use `Maybe` operator instead of `Single`